# Add check constraints to table having data

Tags: sql, sql-server, check-constraints

I have a table with columns `Project, GridID, X, Y, Z`. The table contains lots of data. I would like to add a constraint, with query like given below 
`when GridID='35N' and Project='Hill' then X>=300000 and X<=400000`
Please advise me how I can write this constraint.

I am trying to add a constraint where X is between 300000-400000 and when trying save, it gives me an error that says a conflict has occurred in the table. Why I am seeing this error
Please advise.

Thank you in advance.
Dinesh

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

```
alter table t add constraint chk_grdid_project
    check (not (GridID = '35N' and
                Project = 'Hill' and
                (X < 300000 or X > 400000)
               )
          );
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=2b265b2cf4d568bfe17b672ee8c56c8d) is a db<>fiddle showing that this works.

Comment: Hi Gordan, Thanks for this. Actually I tried the same as per my requirements as query is given below but it is not working                              
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[tblPTSite]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [CK_tblPTSite_Orig_North] CHECK (NOT ([ORIG_GRID_ID]='WGS84_35N' and Project = 'DRC_KiBALI' and ([Orig_North]>300000 or [Orig_North]<400000)))
GO
ALTER TABLE  [dbo].[tblPTSite] CHECK CONSTRAINT [CK_tblPTSite_Orig_North]
GO  Actually what I want in my table is when Grid = WGS84_35N and project=Kibali then the value of X, I would like to restrict between 300000-400000. Please advise.

Comment: Hi Gordan, It is working. Thanks for this. Can I limit the Y coordinate also in the same constraint or I have to add another check constraint. Please advise. I added Y also in same way as X but it did not work.

Comment: @DineshGuleria . . . With the appropriate expression, you can check `Y` as well.